# Solving algebraic equations inolving square terms

Tags: systems-of-equations

How to find the values of $x,y$ and $z$ if 
$3x²-3(1126)x=96y²+24(124)y=8z²-4(734)z $?

I dont have any idea!! I think we can have many values of $x,y$ and $z$ at a time or it is a no solution??

Comment: Well $(x, y, z)=(0, 0, 0)$ is a solution but it's not a very interesting one.

Comment: Oh i see.......

Comment: Why do you write the coefficients this way ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one way to do it is to solve the system 
\begin{align*}
x^2 - 1126 x & =  32 y^2 + 992 y, & (1)\\
z^2 - 367 z & = 12 y^2 + 372 y, & (2)
\end{align*}
as a function of the parameter $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that the discriminant of (1) and (2) are strictly positive and we find the following solutions
\begin{align*}
x_1(y) &= \cfrac{1126 + \sqrt{1126^2 + 4(32 y^2 + 992 y)}}{2},\\
x_2(y) &= \cfrac{1126 - \sqrt{1126^2 + 4(32 y^2 + 992 y)}}{2}, \\
z_1(y) &= \cfrac{367+ \sqrt{367^2 + 4(12 y^2 + 372 y)}}{2},\\
z_2(y) &= \cfrac{367 - \sqrt{367^2 + 4(12 y^2 + 372 y)}}{2}.
\end{align*}
Thus, we need to study the intersections of $x_1$ with $z_1$ and $z_2$ and the ones of $x_2$ with $z_1$ and $z_2$. We note that $x_1$ does not intersect $z_2$ since the minimum of $x_1$ is higher than the maximum of $z_2$. Moreover $x_1$ and $z_1$ do not intersect as well since it means that
$$
\underbrace{(1126 - 367)}_{(1)} + \underbrace{\big(\sqrt{1126^2 + 4(32 y^2 + 992 y)} - \sqrt{367^2 + 4(12 y^2 + 372 y)}\big)}_{(2)} = 0.
$$
This is not possible because (1) and (2) are always positive. Additionally, $x_2$ and $z_1$ do not intersect since the minimum of $z_1$ is again higher than the maximum of $x_2$. It remains to study the intersections of $x_2$ and $z_2$. It consists in solving a fourth order equation and I found the follwing values for $y$
$$
y = 0,\; y = -31,\; y = -31/2 - \sqrt{359503}/10,\; y = -31/2 + \sqrt{359503}/10.
$$

Answer (score 0):

These equations describe the intersection of two quadric surfaces (hyperbolic cylindres), which is a complicated curve. You can parameterize it by writing

$$3x^2-3(1126)x=96y^2+24(124)y=8z^2-4(734)z=t$$

and solving $x,y,z$ in terms of $t$. Note that there will be eight arcs. $t$ must be larger than the highest minimum, which is that of $96y^2+24(124)y$.

There are eight easy points with $t=0$.